# JOIN on JSON_KEYS

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

Tried making this work:

```
SELECT tm.name
FROM taxi t
JOIN taxi_model tm ON JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_KEYS(t.info), CAST(tm.id AS JSON))
WHERE t.id = 1;
```

Table Data:

```
taxi
-----------------------------------------
| id    | info                          |            
|---------------------------------------|
| 1     | {'33': 'foo', '64': 'bar'}    |
-----------------------------------------

taxi_model
---------------------
| id    | name      |            
|-------------------|
| 33    | 'blueTaxi'|
| 64    | 'redTaxi' |
---------------------
```

But not returning `blueTaxi` nor `redTaxi`.
When doing a simple select on JSON_KEYS(t.info), it returns a proper array of taxi_model ids.
Maybe I need to cast JSON_KEYS result to something before the JSON_CONTAINS?

Any help will be appreciated

Version: 5.7.12-log

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT tm.name FROM taxi t
JOIN taxi_model tm ON JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_KEYS(t.info),   JSON_ARRAY(CAST(tm.id AS char)))
WHERE t.id = 1;
```